# If <Shift+D> deletes until the end of the line. Why doesn't <Shift+Y> yank until the end of the line?

Tags: vim

In addition, does `<Shift+Y>` do the same task that `yy` does? Or is there a difference?

Comment: It doesn't because it wasn't written that way.  You can always add that functionality through your .vimrc.

Comment: Indeed `Y` is exactly the same as `yy`. Vim's help is your friend: try `:help yy` `:help Y`

Comment: There's no such thing as `<Shift+D>` and `<Shift+Y>`. It's just `D` and `Y`.

Comment: you can write your own mapping to let `Y` yanking till the EOL.

Comment: @romainl So, what if I wanted to map `<Shift+%>` ? :-P Just kidding

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not Vi compatible. But, as you've observed, a stricter interpretation of vim-ness would be just to yank to the end of the line from the cursor position, which the help agrees with and suggests a mapping for those who want that:

> If you like "Y" to work from the          cursor to the end of
>   line (which is more logical,          but not Vi-compatible) use ":map Y
>   y$".

Comment: rather map it with "nnoremap Y y$"